# jQuery radio button selection check in each loop

Tags: jquery

i have the following jquery code which checks radio buttons and hide or show the associated warning box when none of the radio buttons are selected in each group.

However when i run the code, it takes values of the first checked radio and assigned it to all values of radio buttons (even if they are not selected).

so when i select only the 8th group of radio buttons with a value of 4, in the console i get

6 is checked: 4
7 is checked: 4
8 is checked: 4

but it should print
oh no
oh no
8 is checked: 4

can you help me about this issue?

Thanks.

```
    $.each(checkboxers, function(_, q)
    {
        var warnbox = $('.q' + q);
        if (!!$("input[@name='answer" + q + "']:checked").val()) {
            console.log(q + ' is checked.' + $("input[@name='answer" + q + "']:checked").val());
            warnbox.hide();
        } else {
            console.log('oh no!');
            err = true;
            warnbox.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @popnoodles this is a simple JavaScript syntax for casting to boolean; it's very popular

Comment: More code please. Providing the HTML containing the checkboxes means people can recreate this to check their solution much faster.

Comment: I can honestly say I have never seen that before.

Comment: You're correct it isn't necessary inside an `if`, but it works just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all the @ s and problem solved..